# Transition to a New URL State Without Reload

Tags: angular-ui-router

I'm using [Angular UI Router](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/1.0.0-beta.1/index.html) `1.0.0-beta.1`. Trying to transition from a state like `/myroute/new` to `/myroute/5`. Since the state with the id of 5 is very similar to the `new` state, I'd like to not reset important user state.

I've tried fairly well-documented approaches such as using the `transitionTo` method, like: `$state.transitionTo(myRoute, params, {notify: false});`, but this still refreshes the app.

How can I transition from the first url to the next silently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your property as `dynamic` and then use `$state.params` to read it in the code.

Where you define you state:

```
$stateProvider.state({
    url: '/myroute/:id',
    params: {
        id: {
           dynamic: true
           ...
```

In your controller, inject `$state` and then you can read the params in your logic. You can also put an `uiOnParamsChanged` method on your controller to listen for changed parameters. This is in 1.0.0-beta.3. More reading: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1758